# cannot use cvimageptr -> expression

Tags: cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write a converter from rgb to gray image

and here comes the code :

---

cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;

cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(img_ , enc::MONO8);

sensor_msgs::Image img2_ = cv_ptr->toImageMsg();

image_pub_.publish(img2_, *ci);

---

But the compiler says

/root/catkin_ws/src/usb_cam/nodes/usb_cam_node.cpp:178:51: error: conversion from ‘sensor_msgs::ImagePtr {aka boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_std::allocator<void > >}’ to non-scalar type ‘sensor_msgs::Image’ requested

which maybe means it cannot access the function toImageMsg() from cv_ptr

Hope anyone could help me out of this !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193651/cannot-use-cvimageptr--%3E-expression/) by [fromandto](https://answers.ros.org/users/20325/fromandto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fromandto](https://answers.ros.org/users/20325/fromandto/) on 2014-09-28**:
hi administrator, I wonder if there's anything wrong with my question so it's has not been made public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The call `cv_ptr->toImageMsg();` retuns you an instance of `sensor_msgs::ImagePtr`

See:

http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/classcv__bridge_1_1CvImage.html#a48a7cc72fa96bdf0180d0306543ceb07

In your line

```
sensor_msgs::Image img2_ = cv_ptr->toImageMsg();
```

you attempt to assign the pointer to an object.

So try either:

```
sensor_msgs::Image img2_ = *(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());  // dereference pointer to get content before assigning to object
```

or:

```
sensor_msgs::ImagePtr img2_ = cv_ptr->toImageMsg();  //assign pointer to pointer
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fromandto](https://answers.ros.org/users/20325/fromandto/) on 2014-11-24**:
Your suggestion helps alot , thx!